# When I have macros.gs and 'Copy of macros.gs' in a google sheets project, which is the default?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, multiple-instances

In my Google sheets project I have a macros.gs.  While in Tools-> Script Editor, I made a copy of the macros.gs, which got added with the name 'Copy of macros.gs'.

Which one is selected by default? I assume my Google sheet project uses the latest, not sure how to find the google product version number.  I know it is using the newer version of the editor as of a few weeks ago (April-May 2021).

I am seeing something strange.  I have a timed macro execution on one of these functions in the macros.gs.  I think it selects macros.gs or Copy of macros.gs, by the ordering of the list as I see it.  Most likely the bottom most version.  Is this true?

On the other hand when I open the script editor, it opens by default the Copy version, which is above the macros.gs.  Yes, I can switch the version by selecting from the left panel, after starting the script editor.

I wish to make both the default script editor opening version to be the same as the default version the timed execution uses.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### All function names withing an Apps Script project should be unique

- Hereby it does not matter if the funcitons are located in the same .gs file or in two different ones.
- Having a funciton with the same name both in the original .gs file and in the copy will lead to undesired behavior.

If you want to know which .gs file is the default one you can find it out by making a simple test:

- Create a Macro.gs file within a bound script with the content

```js
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setValue("old script")
}
```

- Make a copy of the macro.gs file
- Change the content of the copy to

```js
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setValue("copy")
}
```

- Create a [custom button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) and assign the function `myFunction` to it

[image]

- Click on the button and see hwat happens:

[image]

**It will be the function of the `copy` that is being called as default.**

If this is not what you want - you need to rename all functions to make sure they have unique names or comment away the funcitons in the script file you do not want to be called.

Comment: ziganotschka, Thank you for the details.  Yes, I understand everything you described.  Perhaps I was not clear enough.

Comment: There is a function to make a copy of a script file.  The results in a new identical file, with all functiion names duplicated, in the same project.  So nobody keeps such a copied file around?  How can this file moved away to another place to store as a backup of my current code ?

Comment: All I want is to make a back up copy of my complex long set of functions, for safe keeping.

Comment: Hello CqN, yes, I understood you. You have several options. For example, if you do create a safety copy as you have done already - comment it away by embedding it in `/*...*/` tags. Another option is to make a copy of the whole spreadsheet - this will also copy the bound script. Or - create a new standalone script project from https://script.google.com/ and copy paste your code for a back-up copy.  You could do the latter also programmatically with the [Apps-Script-API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api), though in your case it would probably be an overkill.